# How to save a dictionary (or any other complex structure) into iCloud using Cloudkit?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit, ckrecord

I need to bind a date to a value and save it into Cloudkit.  Rather than just save a new `CKRecord` for every object and subscript "date" and "value", I would prefer that the `CKRecord` is an array of dictionary: [(date, value)].  I've looked around and can't find any examples of this type of Cloudkit data storage.  I would have thought  by now that Codable would have been bridged over to Cloudkit but I don't see anything indicating that.  There is a [library](https://github.com/insidegui/CloudKitCodable) that handles this but it doesn't handle this type of nesting.  Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `CKRecord` does have the ability to support an `Array`, it is primarily for storing simple data types like strings, numbers, and `CKRecord.Reference`. You don't specifically call out what your 'value' type is, but here is an example of using `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder` to add support for writing/reading any codable type to a `CKRecord`. The encoder/decoder is simply converting the `Encodable`/`Decodable` type to/from a binary `Data` representation, which `CKRecord` also supports.

```swift
private let encoder: JSONEncoder = .init()
private let decoder: JSONDecoder = .init()

extension CKRecord {
    func decode<T>(forKey key: FieldKey) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        guard let data = self[key] as? Data else {
            throw CocoaError(.coderValueNotFound)
        }
        
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
    
    func encode<T>(_ encodable: T, forKey key: FieldKey) throws where T: Encodable {
        self[key] = try encoder.encode(collection)
    }
}
```

Usage would look like the following:

```swift
let collection: [[Date: String]] = [[:]]
let record = CKRecord(recordType: "MyRecord")
try? record.encode(collection, forKey: "collection")
let persisted = try? record.decode(forKey: "collection") as [[Date: String]]
```